# basic error catching in C#

Tags: c#, validation, exception, try-catch

I am needing to have a basic error catching that produces an error statement if the user types in a negative interest rate. Currently I have this loan calculator that produces an error about the negative interest rate but it is in an if else statement. I do have a try catch statement as well, but it only produce an error message if the user types in something other than a number. Any direction/tips on how to have the try catch statement produce the error for my negative interest rate would be great. Thanks

```
namespace Program_3_Car_Calc
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Calculate message box 
    {
        double LoanAmount = 0;
        double Payment = 0;
        double InterestRate = 0;
        double DownPayment = 0;
        int PaymentPeriods = 0;

        // Inputs
        try
        {
            InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(txtRate.Text);
            PaymentPeriods = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToDouble(txtTime.Text) * 12);
            LoanAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtLoan.Text);
            DownPayment = Convert.ToDouble(txtDown.Text);

            // Calculate the monthly payment 
            if (InterestRate > 0)
            {
                InterestRate = InterestRate / 100;
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, Please enter a positive number");
            }

            Payment = ((LoanAmount - DownPayment) * Math.Pow((InterestRate / 12) + 1,
           (PaymentPeriods)) * InterestRate / 12) / (Math.Pow(InterestRate / 12 + 1,
           (PaymentPeriods)) - 1);
           Payment = Math.Round(Payment, 2);

            // Ouptput the results of the monthly payment 
            lblMonthlyPayment.Text = "Your Monthly Payment will be: " + "$" + Payment.ToString   ("N2");

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid character");
        }


    }
    private void CloseGoodbye(string message, string title = " ", int amount = 0) //Optional Parameter for amount of time message box appears 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        MessageBox.Show(message, title);
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void cmdFinished_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Finished Message box 
    {
        CloseGoodbye("Goodbye", "Loan Calc", 1);
    }


}
```

Comment: No, do not use exceptions for this. Exceptions are for _exceptional_ circumstances, not for user input validation. Besides, your try/catch covers too much code, and the catch catches too many exceptions. You have no idea what went wrong when you're in the `catch` block, and you're not even using `catch (Exception ex)` so that  you could possibly find out what went wrong. Very  bad idea.

Comment: You are going in the wrong direction. Input validation should avoid Exceptions whenever possible.

Comment: But if you want to know how to throw (raise an exception), just search for that.

Comment: And you should remove the handling, via exceptions, of non numeric inputs using Double.TryParse....

Comment: You should check your input arguments (at first, if it's exists), then their types (if they could be converted and correct), next your business rules and just after that make calculations. Other words, full validation cycle.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to stick with the `if`/`else` statement.

Avoid using `try`/`catch` to catch preventable errors.  That's not best practice.

---

If you're dead set on throwing an exception, then you can type

```
throw new ArgumentException("You have entered an invalid character");
```

You can technically throw any kind of exception, but `ArguementException` is commonly used for when you have invalid parameters.

Bear in mind that if you catch this exception right away, then the entire purpose of the exception is lost

Comment: I would prefer to use the if/else statement, but the assignment is to have basic error catching if a negative interest rate is entered. Parameters and error catching is what we are learning this week.

Comment: Errors and exceptions are two different things.  Does the assignment specify to alert the user if they enter an invalid value, or does it *explicitly* tell you to use exception handling (i.e. try/catch)?

Comment: @user3677801: Checking user input *is* basic error handling.  If the assignment explicitly states that you should be using exceptions for this, then do the assignment twice.  Once the way it requires, and once the correct way.  If the teacher isn't interested in the correct way, you still should be.

Comment: @Jim Dagg I was assuming we would need to use the try/catch statement since that is what we are learning this week. Maybe I interpret the assignment wrong. "Implement basic error catching, including producing an error if a negative interest rate is entered."

Comment: @David you make a good point about turning in both ways. I do want to learn the correct way.

Comment: @user3677801: In that case you're looking for the `TryParse()` method.  (`double` has one, `int` has one, etc.)  You can find plenty of examples online of how to use it.  Essentially it uses an `out` parameter for the number and returns a boolean indicating whether or not parsing was successful.  You'd use that boolean in an `if` to check if the input string was a parseable number.

Comment: @Sam I am I went ahead and tried the throw new with the ArgumentException. Maybe I am doing it wrong, but when the user entered in a negative number the results were just 0, because it does not like me having the messagebox.show....

Comment: @user3677801 All my answer does is allows you to make the exception happen.  You'll still need to catch it, and you'll still need the `if` statements.  You'd replace `messagebox.show` with `throw new ArgumentException("You have entered an invalid character");`, and an exception should be thrown if that line gets executed.  The exception will have a `Message` property which is the string you passed into the exception constructor.